# Is there a bracket missing in teubner.sty?

Tags: environments, brackets, debugging

When TeXifying files where I use teubner.sty, LaTeX complains

```
Runaway argument?
{\setcounter {verso}{##1}\def \writ@verso {\count 255=\value {verso}\divide \ETC
.
! File ended while scanning use of \@newenv.
```

Seems to be about line 998 in teubner.sty:

```
\newenvironment{Versi}[1][1]{% <-- there it is
    \setcounter{verso}{#1}%
    \def\writ@verso{%
        \count255=\value{verso}\divide\count255by5\relax
...
```

A wizard of the most honorable order of Gnu might be able to see it at once: Is the bracket actually unclosed? Where do I have to insert the closing bracket? The macro seems to run from line 996 (`\newif\ifBreakVersi`) to line 1045 (`\let\Versus\Versi \let\endVersus\endVersi`).

Comment: And please add a compilable example so we have a test case.

Comment: Yes, there should be a `}` more at the end of line 1009. You can fix it yourself in the code, waiting for the author to download a fixed version.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is about a bug in a package that has been fixed. Latest releases/uses of this package should not have this problem anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following screenshot from [the diff in the repository of TeX Live](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/teubner/teubner.sty?sortby=date&r1=36066&r2=36065&pathrev=36066)

[image]

shows the problem. In the previous version (4.3, 2014/10/02) the code was

```
\def\\{\@ifstar{\v@rscr{\@M}}{\v@rscr{\z@}}}%
```

and in the new version (4.5, 2015/01/14) it is

```
\def\acapo{\@ifstar{\v@rscr{\@M}}{\v@rscr{\z@}}%
\let\\\acapo
```

and it can clearly be seen that the definition of `\acapo` is not finished.

There's nothing that can be done except:

1. make the problem known to the package maintainer
2. fix manually the missing brace in `teubner.sty`

If you're afraid about modifying a typo in a `.sty` file, then make a local copy of `teubner.sty` and fix that one.

---

### Upgrade, January 19, 2015

The bug has been fixed in version 4.5a, released 2015/01/18.

Comment: The author appears to be already aware of this: [the fix will be available in the next days on CTAN](http://www.guitex.org/home/it/forum/5-tex-e-latex/99337-errore-con-teubner#99337).